# Compojure: lein-ring in production?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure

It seems that people sugget the use of lein-ring for a no-brainer deploy of a Compojure application. Isn't it just meant for development? I've benchmarked the same app running with lein-ring vs packed by leiningen with uberjar (executed with java -jar, it contains ring-jetty).

To my surprise, the performance is even slightly better with lein-ring! Am I missing something?

How can i keep on using lein-ring but avoid printing out stacktraces in case of exceptions and avoid checking for modified files?

Thanks

Comment: What measures lead you to conclude the performance of lein-ring to be "slightly better"? Have you tried comparing the performance against "lein run"? Here's a suitable project.clj: https://github.com/4clojure/4clojure/blob/develop/project.clj

Answer (score 3):

lein-ring will allow you to readily produce a war file for deployment to a container (and serves as the basis for [lein-beanstalk](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-beanstalk)
 for easy deployment to Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk), but I'm not aware of a common practice of using it in production.  Certainly an option, but probably rarely the best one.  I'd recommend deploying using the methods recommended by your host / container; this will most often mean deploying a war (which lein-ring can be used to build) or using some variety of containerless deployment with an embedded Jetty instance (as on [Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure) with Leiningen).

If you *do* want to use lein-ring in production but want to turn off its development-time capabilities (code reloading, stack trace rendering, etc), you must set the `RING_ENV` environment variable to `production`, e.g.:

```
export RING_ENV=production
lein ring ...
```

Answer (score 0):

lein-ring is a development only tool. Of course the way you package and deploy your application will have an impact on performance. Are you actually comparing apples to apples here?

I have found significant differences in lein-ring and even just an embedded jetty deployment.

This being said, with lein-ring you miss out on a ton of stuff. Putting your application in a proper container will allow for a lot more in terms of opertional support and monitorability.