# How to serve Clojure pages with nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, clojure

I set up a home server with ubuntu and ngingx and I can serve static files. Now I want to test some clojure files but I am not clear about how to do this. For php this seems very easy, for instance [in this tutorial](http://www.farinspace.com/nginx-virtual-host/) he adds a location for php files. Is that all I need to do, just indicate where Clojure files are in the config file?

I have the *Web Development with Clojure* by Dmitry Sotnikov and he talks about deployment but not specifically about nginx.

Can you point me in the right direction where I can find documentation about this?

Comment: read also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787911/compojure-lein-ring-in-production

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider next setup:

```
nginx -> ring server (jetty)
```

You need to start `lein ring server` (using [lein-ring](https://github.com/weavejester/lein-ring) plugin) on some port (say 8080). Nginx will listen at 80 port and forward requests to 8080.
Here is a sample nginx config:

```
upstream ring {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    root <path-to-public-dir>;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file
        try_files $uri $uri/ @ring;
    }

    location @ring {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://ring;
    }

    location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts|stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
        expires     max;
        add_header  Cache-Control public;
    }
}
```

Change **path-to-public-dir** to directory where your static files reside (*resources/public*).
Nginx will server static files (if file found) and forward other requests to ring server.

Comment: Lein should not be run from production. Use lein uberjar to create a server jar.

Comment: I created a project with lein called `guestbook` and I did `lein ring server` which is running on `localhost:3000` and I see "Hello World" in the browser. I changed the conf file to "3000" from "8080" that you had (correct?) but now I am confused where I need to put the project files. At this point they are in `~/guestbook`. Can you help with this?

Comment: great, now change in nginx config: `root /home/zeynel/guestbook/resources/public` (make sure folder exists) and visit http://localhost/. This should hit your ring server.

Comment: ok, but I am still confused. If I change `root ~/guestbook/resources/public` where do I put put my html files, like index.html?

Comment: If it's a static page you can put it in public folder and request /index.html. For dynamic responses you need to learn about compojure routes - https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki

Comment: I created the `~/guestbook/resources/public/html/index.html` file and made it the root in the nginx config file but I get "Not Found` when I try `http://localhost:3000/index.html`. I think that I am not really understanding what is going on here. I think nginx is not involved in this process at all. localhost is just the server that I started with `lein ring server`. I will ask a new question with more details with my setup. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try http://localhost/html/index.html. You are correct, nginx serves 80 port (url without a port), ring server listen on 3000 port. So you hit ring server not nginx. You are welcome!

Comment: ok, `http://localhost:3000/html/index.html` works, `localhost/html/index.html` does not work. But, I realized that my confusion is because I want to use my own domain `example.com` not `localhost`. So I think I need to start over.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43450/discussion-between-edbond-and-zeynel)

Answer (score 9):

Please try [Nginx-Clojure](https://github.com/xfeep/nginx-clojure) module. You can run clojure Ring handlers with Nginx without any Java Web Server, eg. Jetty.
Further more it 's very fast. The benchmarks can be found [HERE](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/clojure-web-server-benchmarks).

[image]