# How do I run nginx as proxy to jetty?

Tags: java, nginx, clojure, proxy, jetty

I have this setup:

I installed nginx and Jetty on an ubuntu machine that I am using as the server. I tested Jetty and it is running on 0.0.0.0.:8080 and I see the Jetty Welcome page.

The domain that I will be using is nomilkfor.me. The nginx conf file is in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/nomilkfor.me.conf`.

I am programming on an another laptop (OSX) and I created a project `web_test` with lein. I created a `.war` file of `web_test` and when I run `lein ring server` I see the content of `core.clj` on the browser.

Initially, I set up nginx conf file after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632987/how-to-serve-clojure-pages-with-nginx/20637601#20637601) but I could not make it work.

I want to ask how I can fix the conf file below (with my questions) and how to deploy web_test with nginx as proxy to jetty.

I pasted the conf file below and added my questions for each directive:

```
# what should the ip address and port be?
# i assume this instructs nginx to send request it receives on port 80 to Jetty server
upstream ring {
    server ????? fail_timeout=0;
}

# what directory do I need to enter here?
# do I use the clojure project root?
# do I use ~/web_test/src ?
server {
    root /?????;

    # make site accessible from http://localhost
    server_name nomilkfor.me;

    location / {
        # first attempt to serve request as file
        try_files $uri $uri/ @ring;
    }

    # we will need to understand these settings
    location @ring {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # what do I use here???
        # is http://ring; correct???
        proxy_pass http://ring;
    }

    location ~ ^(assets|images|javascript|stylesheets|system)/ {
        expires    max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is my third question about the same subject but I still could not solve. Thanks for all the help.

- [Can I use Clojure with nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666497/can-i-use-clojure-with-nginx)
- [How to serve clojure pages with nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632987/how-to-serve-clojure-pages-with-nginx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server` should contains ip:port of upstream server (jetty is your case).

`root` is the web root folder where your static files reside. Nginx will look for files there. Such folder usually named 'public' because it's accessible from outside. For example `/js/bootstrap.min.js` request will make nginx search for `public/js/bootstrap.min.js` (see `try_files` directive). If such file not found request will be forwarded to jetty server.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. But now I am having another problem, Jetty is not working for me. I already asked several questions here and in SuperUser about jetty. I cannot even remove it. Can you recommend another server I can use instead of jetty? I looked into resin but it seems that it is not suitable for beginners. Are there any easier to use server that I can try?