# How do I specify URIs in nginx conf file?

Tags: java, nginx

I am trying to understand the following nginx conf file ([from here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/1mrsmx/whats_the_common_way_to_use_ring/)). What should I replace `@example_app` with?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  rewrite ^(.+?)/?$ http://www.example.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  root /var/www/example.com/public_html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @example_app;
  }

  location @example_app {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
  }

}
```

---

**EDIT**

I changed my config file to this. Is this better? I adapted it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705984/how-do-i-run-nginx-as-proxy-to-jetty). I also added my domain and ip address to `/etc/hosts`

```
 upstream ring {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @ring;
        }

        location @ring {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://ring;
        }

        location ~ ^/(assets|images|javascripts/stylesheets|swfs|system)/ {
        expires     max;
        add_header  Cache-Control public;
        }
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to replace `@example_app` with anything if you don't want. It is simply just a named location and could easily be changed to `@whatever`. You just need to make sure that if you reference a named location with `try_files` that you need define the same location in your config file.

The comments on Reddit explain the config fairly well but to reiterate:

1) The first server block redirects any requests from example.com to www.example.com
2) The second server block catches requests to www.example.com
3) The `location /` block catches all requests within this server block and try the list of options from `try_files` - first trying to load any matching files at that path otherwise using the named location @example_app
4) The `location @example_app` block is a named location and proxy passes the request to port 5000 on the same server.

Comment: I am sorry this turned out to be so confusing to me. In the meantime I changed the config file to match the earlier answer. I edited my question can you please take a look?