# How do I configure nginx as proxy to jetty?

Tags: java, nginx, jetty, ring

I've been trying to set up nginx as proxy to jetty. I want to do something as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632987/how-to-serve-clojure-pages-with-nginx/20637601#20637601) but for Jetty not ring.

I've created a `.war` and I placed it in `~/jetty/jetty-dist/webapps/web_test-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.war`

Say, I want to use the domain example.com with ip address 198.51.100.0.

I've also copied `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` into the file `example.com` and I have it in the same directory.

Can you help me configure nginx as proxy to jetty in my case? I know there are many references online about how to do this but they are all different and I got confused.

What specific changes do I need to make in nginx? What changes do I need to make in jetty.xml? Do I need to make any other changes? Will my app be served at example.com/index.html?

Current state of nginx is copied below:

```
upstream jetty {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://jetty

                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

---

**EDIT**

I was wondering if I need to use Jetty at all. In [this setup](http://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/1mrsmx/whats_the_common_way_to_use_ring/ccciqhx) he just uses ring, which seems super easy? What do I gain by using jetty?

---

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How to configure  nginx to work with a java server. In the example Jetty is used.

Edit `/etc/nginx/sites-available/hostname`:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  hostname.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass       http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }
}
```

Consider disabling external access to port 8080:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 8080 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

An example Jetty configuration (`jetty.xml`) might resemble:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<!--
 | http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-connectors.html
 +-->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Set name="secureScheme">https</Set>
    <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.tls.port" default="8443" /></Set>
    <Set name="outputBufferSize">65536</Set>
    <Set name="requestHeaderSize">8192</Set>
    <Set name="responseHeaderSize">8192</Set>
  </New>
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="http.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="http.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig" /></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" default="localhost" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8080" /></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

This will cause Jetty to listen on **localhost:8080** and nginx to redirect requests from **domain.com:80** to the Jetty server.

Comment: in Jetty 6, if you had

${jetty.home}/contexts/myapp.xml
With Jetty 9.0, move it to

${jetty.home}/webapps/myapp.xml
With Jetty 9.1+, move it to

${jetty.base}/webapps/myapp.xml